# get global var of mousemove and update onFrame event in paper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paperjs

I am new to [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) therefore might this a basic question but I am trying to the the following:

```
var xpos;
var ypos;

function onMouseMove(event) {

   xpos = event.point.x;
   ypos = event.point.y;

}
```

get the current mouseposition and save it as the variables `xpos` and `ypos`

```
function onFrame(event) {

   path.segments[1].point.x = path.segments[1].point.x+xpos/10;
   path.segments[1].point.y = path.segments[1].point.y+ypos/10;

}
```

and then use them to update the `onFrame` animation. But it does not work, how can I update the animation with the new values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is increasing the position of `path.segments[1]` every frame. I believe what you want is to subtract a portion of the difference between the segment and mouse positions per frame.

Try this:

```
var path = new Path.Line((0,0), view.center);
path.strokeColor = "black";
var pos = new Point(0, 0);
function onMouseMove(event) {
   pos = event.point;
}
function onFrame(event) {
   path.segments[1].point += (pos - path.segments[1].point) / 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, this was indeed the thing I was searching for. Since I am normally using Raphael.js its a little bit tough the rethink all. But may I be cheeky and as you something how could I archive the same effect with an additional bezier point in the middle of a path. While the beginning point and the end point are fixed, and the bezierpoints goes with onMouseMove?